# Hashing an image from a remote location in PHP

Tags: php

Using a PHP script, I want to compare two images. One of the images is located on my server, and one is located on an external website. I have tried to compare the hashes of the two images to each other. Unfortunately, this only works when the two images are saved on my server. How can I make this work?

```
<?php

$localimage = sha1_file('image.jpg');

$imagelink = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/image.jpg');  
$ext_image = sha1_file($imagelink);

if($localimage == $ext_image){
    //Do something
}

?>
```

Comment: Download the image to your server and then compare them?

Comment: @DanLowe The problem is when I want to do that with thousands of images, it would simply take too much space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using php **5.1+** (which I hope) you can just write :

```
<?php

$localimage = sha1_file('image.jpg');
$ext_image = sha1_file('http://www.google.com/image.jpg');

if($localimage == $ext_image){
    //Do something
}

?>
```

As sha1_file will work on remote wrappers.

Quote from PHP doc at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php

> 5.1.0 Changed the function to use the streams API. It means that you can use it with wrappers, like sha1_file('http://example.com/..')

Comment: The code you posted before the edit works fine. Thanks a lot! I will try this code as well.

Comment: yes i edited since this is the "proper" and shorter way to do it.

Comment: But be aware that this will download the images to your server anyway.
It won't use disk space since it's only  temporary but will use a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: He was going to have to use that bandwidth anyway, so that should not be any different to any other way.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the `sha1_file()` properly in the second call.

`sha1_file()` expects the parameter to be a filename and you are using a memory buffer. So you have 2 options.

First using your current code, save the file to a temp location and use `sha1_file()`

```
<?php
   $localimage = sha1_file('image.jpg');

   $imagelink = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/image.jpg');  
   file_put_contents('temp.jpg', $imagelink);
   $ext_image = sha1_file('temp.jpg');

   if($localimage == $ext_image){
      //Do something
   }
?>
```

Or use `sha1()` instead of `sha1_file()` on the contents of `$imagelink`

```
<?php
   $localimage = sha1_file('image.jpg');

   $imagelink = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/image.jpg');  
   $ext_image = sha1($imagelink);

   if($localimage == $ext_image){
      //Do something
   }
?>
```

Well actually maybe 3 options, see @Flunch's answer!

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of storing it using `file_put_contents`. Which of the two ways would you suggest regarding speed and efficiency?

Comment: I would try the solution from @Flunch first see if that works. I had forgotten about that way. If that way works, even I will give his answer an upvote!

Comment: I can hereby confirm that the solution of @Flunch works for me.